# How to use bootstrap date and timepicker inside a modal pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the Date and time picker inside a modal pop-up window.  I am able to display the date Picker but unable to display time picker inside the modal window, When I click on the input text field of time picker  it is displaying behind the modal window.

Here is my html code:-

HTML Code:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade in" style="display: block; margin-top:100px;" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="main padder"> 
<table>
<tr>
  <td>              
    <input type="text" id="multiStartDate" name="multiStartDate" class="datepicker form-control" />                             
  </td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="multiStartTime" name="multiStartTime" class="form-control timepicker"/>  
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="multiEndDate" name="multiEndDate"   class="form-control timepicker" />
</td>
<td>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-md btn-orange btn-info m-r-small" id="addNewDate">Add</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
.datepicker { 
       z-index: 100000 !important; 
       display: block; 
    }

    .timepicker{
       z-index: 100001 !important;
    }
```

Here is the Js code :

I am using the Backbone.js frame work :

So in my backbone.js view:

```
onShow : function(){

         $('#multiStartDate').datepicker({
        format: "mm-dd-yyyy", 
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight:true
        });

        $('#modal').modal('show');
        $('#multiStartTime').timepicker();
        },
```

Comment: This is more of a css z-index issue

Comment: It's probably an issue with z-index. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: make a fiddle!.. pls

Comment: Here is the fiddle:        https://jsfiddle.net/pogmg1r4/9/

Answer (score 2):

Hi I came back across this question today and when i looked at your fiddle, the first thing I noticed was that you didn't even have the datepicker js or timepicker js included! They don't come included in bootstrap! You do actually have to include BOTH `css` and `js` for each!

So I got it working anyway - I didn't actually get the time arrows going, but you should seriously look at the development pages on Github, for both

This is the link for the [timepicker](https://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) page  - check it out

https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/x3ek9mjx/

Hope this helps

Rach

Comment: by the way i came across a combined datetime picker https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ - that might save time?

Comment: this fiddle is better https://jsfiddle.net/9hL5mzwb/1/ I discovered after a search that the arrows missing thing is an open issue for the past 5 months or so!

Comment: ,Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add css for your datetimepicker, it is rendering but is behind your modal so you need to increase the z-index of your datetimepicker inside the modal open event like

```
$("#modal").on("show.bs.modal",   function(){
 $("#multiStartTime").css("z-index","999"); 
 });
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the response still it is not working ,Can you please create a fiddle so that it would be easy for me to go forward.